# selenium и Яндекс браузер, помогите с ошибкой

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1 скрин ошибка, 2 код
Яндекс драйвер, скинул в папку с питоном и добавил драйвер через переменные среды в Path

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения данной проблемы, в первую очередь необходимо узнать что "говорит" ошибка.

Google-переводчик: "Предупреждение об устаревании: executable_path устарел, передайте объект службы".

Это значит executable_path устарел, и нужно использовать Service()

Как вариант - мои действия по установке.

1. Ищем самый свежий релиз yandexdriver. На данный момент это 23.3.0
   (https://github.com/yandex/YandexDriver/releases/tag/v23.3.0-stable)

   Скачиваем драйвер и добавляем его в PATH.
2. Пробуем запустить базовый код для проверки работоспособности
   драйвера.

   Код есть тут: https://github.com/yandex/YandexDriver

   Продублировал для удобства:

```python
from selenium import webdriver options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

binary_yandex_driver_file = 'yandexdriver.exe' # path to
YandexDriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(binary_yandex_driver_file,
options=options) driver.get('https://yandex.ru') driver.quit()
```

3. Радуемся рабочему драйверу и пишем свою программу :)

Comment: Уже сделал, версию selenium старую накатил и разобрался с драйвером, спасибо)